# When are flags marked "aged away"?

Tags: support, flags

Please note that I'm fully aware *why* flags age away and I know what alternate actions I can take.

I was looking through my flags, and I noticed something odd. A rather recent flag (flagged one week ago) was already marked as "Aged Away". Meanwhile, older flags (two to three weeks ago) are still "Pending Review".

This behavior confused me, as I was under the impression that flags spend *x* amount of time in the CV queue before being marked as "Aged Away".

Is there any set rule on *when* flags turn to "Aged Away"?

Comment: Related: [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system):

> - If the question has less than 100 views, the votes expire one per day after 14 days.
> - If the question has [100 or more] views, close votes expire at a rate of one per day, starting 4 days after the last vote was cast.

If you flag a post on a high-traffic tag, your flag will age away faster than a flag on a low-traffic tag.

Since my flagged post reached >100 views, it got marked as "Aged Away" faster than some other flags, on lower-traffic tags, where the posts have not reached 100 views yet.

Comment: What if the question has exactly 100 views???

Comment: @dwirony, I think it just teeters on in Purgatory indefinitely until finally falling over into the edge of more than 100 views (which should happen eventually, you'd figure).

Comment: @dwirony difficult to say; whenever anyone visits them...

Comment: That's a ridiculously short time frame... I thought it was longer than that.

Comment: @dwirony The quote in this answer is incorrect. If you click on the link in the answer, it says that questions with 100 views have their votes expire after four days.

Comment: The linked post is about flags, although it links to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902/322419) which is about close votes

Comment: @Zanna yes and the answer says: `These [flag aging rules] follow the normal rules for close vote aging`